# C# .NET Background Service

Tags: c#, windows, service, background

i'm investing to develop a background service in c#. 
I need to create a service that listens to 'request' that comes from the browser and that makes actions depending on what I send. 
The service is ready but I do not know how to make it run in the background such as these programs:

[image]

What I want to do also is to get a poster (as usually do the antivirus) to warn the user that is interacting with the aplicaicon web. Where I can document to achieve this. I have not found anything on the internet.
Many thanks.

PD: In Windows, linux or Mac is not necessary.

Comment: What have you tried?  Without including any code, it seems like you just want people to write your program for you (so this post will likely get downvoted and close, FYI)

Comment: Not at all, I just want to know where to document, I do not want them to give me code. It is that I have been looking for information about it and I have not found anything.

Answer (score 2):

Windows services don't utilize the system tray. If you want your application to utilize the system tray what you want to create is a WPF application, there you can define tray icons and context menu actions. Heres a little snippet of how to achieve the tray icon in your application.

```
    var trayIcon = new NotifyIcon
    {
        Icon        = Properties.Resources.ssms,
        ContextMenu = New ContextMenu(),
        Visible     = true,
        Text        = "Name"         
    };
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks with that I have where to start. regards.